# Capital letter “L” in Oxford English Dictionary entry

Tags: meaning, grammar, dictionaries

[image]

I just started Snow Crash by Neal Stephenson and am wondering what the “L.” in the first line of the definition for “virus” means. I checked the online Oxford English Dictionary commonly used abbreviations page but found nothing meaningful.

As a side question, why are there brackets around that definition? Was Stephenson adding his own definition?

Comment: Do you really mean OED (which does have it, under [initialisms](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/104665)) or [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/l) which doesn't? It would be helpful if OED put it [where one might expect to find it](https://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-symbols-and-other-conventions/), but if all else fails, look in the dictionary itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The L stands for Latin, which is the origin of the English word. The brackets around that definition are used to separate the Latin definition from the English definition.